# How to save multiple CKRecords with CloudKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, synchronization, cloudkit

The CKDatabase class only have a method to save a record to the cloud.
Is there any other way to save multiple records to the cloud?

```
CKRecordID *artworkRecordID = [[CKRecordID alloc] initWithRecordName:@"116"];
CKRecord *artworkRecord = [[CKRecord alloc] initWithRecordType:@"Artwork" recordID:artworkRecordID];
artworkRecord[@"title" ] = @"MacKerricher State Park";
artworkRecord[@"artist"] = @"Mei Chen";
artworkRecord[@"address"] = @"Shenzhen";

CKContainer *myContainer = [CKContainer defaultContainer];
CKDatabase *privateDatabase = myContainer.privateCloudDatabase;
[privateDatabase saveRecord:artworkRecord completionHandler:^(CKRecord * _Nullable record, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    dispatch_sync_on_main_queue(^{
        if (error) {
            self.titleLabel.text = @"Error";
            self.subTitleLabel.text = error.description;
        } else {
            self.titleLabel.text = @"Successfully";
        }
    });
}];
```

Comment: Use `CKModifyRecordsOperation`.

Comment: @rmaddy How? Can you provide a example code ?

Comment: @rmaddy, Oh,I see. Thank you very much.